# ArcGIS Pro 3.0.4 Network Analyst service area error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, network-analyst, service-area, error-030024

I am constantly getting ERROR 030024: Solve returned a failure, in ArcGIS Pro, trying to solve service area away from the point using 56 km as a driving distance with ArcGIS Online data. Unable to generate lines and polygons. Sometimes when polygon is created, it is different with the same parameters. New to ArcGIS Pro, used ArcMap.

Comment: Messages

Start Time: Sunday, February 19, 2023 11:40:53 PM
Executing network analysis service Job Id: "j8192e2079a3944b7aa79b730f4002aac".
Submitted.
Executing...
ERROR 030136: The largest break value, 112, exceeds the threshold, 24.140 Kilometers, set to generate detailed polygons.
Failed to execute (GenerateServiceAreas).
Failed.
ERROR 030024: Solve returned a failure.
Failed to execute (Solve).
Failed at Sunday, February 19, 2023 11:40:59 PM (Elapsed Time: 5.71 seconds)